# Remove note about bash that appears when opening the terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I tried instaling ROOT by CERN by following steps described by certain people. But although that was unsuccessful, I keep getting the following line when I open a new terminal.

```
bash: /home/USER/bin/thisroot.sh: No such file or directory
```

How can I remove that?
EDIT- Please note, for those who have raised the doubts, that I have redacted my true username. And I wrote USER in that place.

Comment: Look in `.bashrc` in your home directory.

Comment: Is it literally the string `"USER"` or are you redacting personal information?

Comment: redacting my username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably an alias on your .bashrc or .bash_profile calling that file, so it tries to load it everytime you get a new prompt.

Try editing them with one of these commands:

```
gedit $HOME/.bashrc
gedit $HOME/.bash_profile
gedit $HOME/.profile
```

Look for any line loading 'thisroot.sh' and comment it (write a # character at the begining of those lines). If you see after saving and opening a terminal that all works well, you can go ahead and directly deleting those lines.

Also, the way the script is being called sounds wrong, shouldn't it be /home/**YOURUSERNAMEHERE**/bin/thisroot.sh?

Comment: yes, of course, it is "myusernamethere"... ;-)  I am just redacting my personal information.

Comment: the first statement solved my problem. many thanks !